# How to make one combobox dependent on other in jsp page with ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

When i call the jquery code from combobox then from where i should fetch the details of other combobox?

For ex: if i select CSE branch then where the xhr request should go to JAVA page or JSP page

And if the request goes to JAVA servlet then what is the exact way to perform this?

```
    enter code here<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<%@page import="model.to.BranchInfo"%>
<%@include file="meta.jsp" %>
       <title>Blog Single | Corlate</title>

    <%@include file="css.jsp" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("document").ready(function(){
         $("#value").change(function(){
             var val = $(this).val();
             var address ="ajaxsubject.jsp?value=" + val;
             $.ajax({url:address,success:function(result){
             $("#div").html(result);
             }});
         }) ;
      });
        </script>

</head><!--/head-->
<body>
    <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
    <br>
    <form method="get">
<label for="bname">Choose Branch Name</label> 
<select name="branch_id" class="form-control" id="value">
                        <option selected="selected">Select a branch</option>
                        <c:if test="${allbranch!=null}">
                        <c:forEach var="item" items="${allbranch}">
                            <option value="${item.branch_id}">${item.branch_id}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:if>
                        </select>

    <br><br>
    <section>
    <div id="div" >


    </div>



    </section>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want to change `var address ="ajaxsubject.jsp?value=" + val;` so that is goes to a Servlet or Rest Web service

Comment: i mean what should i use as address
1. A jsp page like in the code
or 2. A java servlet

Comment: write the servlet or webservice, then call it.  The address that you use to call it can be used in your Ajax

Comment: Do not put Java code in your JSP.  Use servlets or webservices

Comment: the code for new combobox should appear in same page or the page which is called in address??

Comment: as your code shows `$("#div").html(result);`

Comment: if(request.getParameter("value")== "CSE")
         {
   List<SubjectInfo> allsubject = HibernateViewUtil.getAllSubjectsCSE();
   request.setAttribute("allsubject",allsubject);
  
         }

What to do after this if i use servlet?